# Ipad 10.2 screen has deeper color than my other hardware

Tags: ipad, screen, color, drawing

I've just bought an iPad 10.2 with an Apple Pencil for the purpose of using it as a portable drawing tablet.  After finishing two pictures on it, I can say that it has some kind of a noticeable skew in its color/brightness/contrast for some reason.

Both my Android phone and my PC's flatscreen show that what looked like deep and crisp color.  However, the 10.2 screen looks way lighter, more blurry and with far more noticeable brush edges where there were none on the iPad.

I was drawing in Ibis Paint, but judging by the fact that opening the image in the tablet's gallery app gave me the same results, it looks like the problem is either with the hardware, or with the system settings.

How do I make it work without manually tweaking every picture on my PC afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have accurately calibrated all your screens with a hardware colorimeter, then the chances are the iPad is the most accurate "out of the box".

Most devices' screens tend to be 'punched up' by the manufacturers to look good on the shop floor. If uncorrected after purchase, this can lead to very misleading colour workflows. Apple tends to do this less and instead relies on the deep colour capabilities of the screen itself - which can handle [P3 colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCI-P3), not just the [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) common to most devices.

There's a good blog on how this can be perceived visually on [IconFactory - Looking at the Future](https://blog.iconfactory.com/2016/04/looking-at-the-future/) with some good imagery to test & some hints as to how to manage colour across platforms - something about which entire books have been written.